# Generalization of Inkeri's primality test

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

How to prove that a claim given below is true ?

---

**Definition**

Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot \left(\left(x-\sqrt{x^2-4}\right)^{m}+\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-4}\right)^{m}\right)$ ,

where $m$ and $x$ are nonnegative integers .

---

**Theorem** (Inkeri)

Let $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ with $n\ge 2$ .

Let $S_i=P_{2}(S_{i-1})$ with $S_0=8$

then ,

$F_n$ is prime iff $S_{2^n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{F_n}$

---

**Claim**

Let $N=k\cdot b^n+1$ such that $n>2$ , $0<k<b^n$ ,

$k \equiv 1,7 \pmod{30}$ , $b$ is even , $3 \not \mid b$ , $5 \not \mid b$ and $n \equiv 0 \pmod{4} $ .

Let $S_i=P_b(S_{i-1})$ with $S_0=P_{kb/2}(P_{b/2}(8))$

then ,

$N$ is prime iff $S_{n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$

---

For $b=2$ I managed to prove a claim , at least I think so . You can see my proof in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03444.pdf) (Theorem 3.4.) . But I have no idea how to prove this claim for $b>2$ .

Any hint will be greatly appreciated .

Comment: http://folk.uib.no/nmaoy/papers/luc.pdf  is a nicer way to do Sun's method, and was published 12 years earlier.

Comment: @DanaJ Thanks for the link .

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer.

This answer proves the following :

$$\text{if $N$ is prime, then $S_{n-2}\equiv 0\pmod N$}\tag0$$

**Proof** :

First of all, we prove by induction that
$$S_i=p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4}\tag1$$
where $p=4-\sqrt{15}, q=4+\sqrt{15}$ with $pq=1$.

Proof for $(1)$ :

$$S_0=P_{kb/2}(P_{b/2}(8))$$$$\small=2^{-kb/2}\left(2^{-b/2}\cdot\left((2p)^{b/2}+(2q)^{b/2}\right)-(q^{b/2}-p^{b/2})\right)^{kb/2}+2^{-kb/2}\left(2^{-b/2}\cdot\left((2p)^{b/2}+(2q)^{b/2}\right)+(q^{b/2}-p^{b/2})\right)^{kb/2}$$
$$=\left(p^{b/2}\right)^{kb/2}+\left(q^{b/2}\right)^{kb/2}=p^{kb^2/4}+q^{kb^2/4}$$

Supposing that $(1)$ holds for $i$ gives
$$S_{i+1}=P_b(S_i)=2^{-b}\left(p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4}-\sqrt{\left(p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4}\right)^2-4}\right)^{b}+2^{-b}\left(p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4}+\sqrt{\left(p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4}\right)^2-4}\right)^{b}$$
$$=2^{-b}\left(p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4}-\left(q^{kb^{i+2}/4}-p^{kb^{i+2}/4}\right)\right)^{b}+2^{-b}\left(p^{kb^{i+2}/4}+q^{kb^{i+2}/4}+\left(q^{kb^{i+2}/4}-p^{kb^{i+2}/4}\right)\right)^{b}$$
$$=p^{kb^{i+3}/4}+q^{kb^{i+3}/4}\qquad\blacksquare$$

Let $N=k\cdot b^n+1$. Then, from $(1)$, we have
$$S_{n-2}=p^{kb^{n}/4}+q^{kb^{n}/4}=p^{(N-1)/4}+q^{(N-1)/4}$$

Now, in order to prove that $S_{n-2}\equiv 0\pmod N$, it is sufficient to prove that $S_{n-2}^2\equiv 0\pmod N$, i.e.
$$p^{(N-1)/2}+q^{(N-1)/2}\equiv -2\pmod N$$

We use 
$$p^{(N+3)/2}+q^{(N+3)/2}=(p+q)(p^{(N+1)/2}+q^{(N+1)/2})-(p^{(N-1)/2}+q^{(N-1)/2})\tag2$$

Using that
$$\sqrt{4\pm\sqrt{15}}=\frac{\sqrt{10}\pm\sqrt 6}{2}$$
we have
$$\begin{align}&2^{N+1}(p^{(N+1)/2}+q^{(N+1)/2})\\&=\left(\sqrt{10}-\sqrt 6\right)^{N+1}+\left(\sqrt{10}+\sqrt 6\right)^{N+1}\\&=\sum_{i=0}^{N+1}\binom{N+1}{i}(\sqrt{10})^i((-\sqrt 6)^{N+1-i}+(\sqrt 6)^{N+1-i})\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{(N+1)/2}\binom{N+1}{2j}(\sqrt{10})^{2j}\cdot 2(\sqrt{6})^{N+1-2j}\\&\equiv 2\cdot 6^{(N+1)/2}+10^{(N+1)/2}\cdot 2\qquad\pmod N\\&\equiv 2\cdot (-6)+(-10)\cdot 2\qquad\pmod N\\&\equiv -32\qquad\pmod N\end{align}$$
(because $6^{(N-1)/2}\equiv -1\equiv 10^{(N-1)/2}\pmod N$) from which we have
$$p^{(N+1)/2}+q^{(N+1)/2}\equiv -8\qquad\pmod N$$
since $2^{N+1}\equiv 4\pmod N$ is coprime to $N$.

Also,
$$\small\begin{align}&2^{N+3}(p^{(N+3)/2}+q^{(N+3)/2})\\&=\left(\sqrt{10}-\sqrt 6\right)^{N+3}+\left(\sqrt{10}+\sqrt 6\right)^{N+3}\\&=\sum_{i=0}^{N+3}\binom{N+3}{i}(\sqrt{10})^i((-\sqrt 6)^{N+3-i}+(\sqrt 6)^{N+3-i})\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{(N+3)/2}\binom{N+3}{2j}(\sqrt{10})^{2j}\cdot 2(\sqrt 6)^{N+3-2j}\\&\equiv 2\cdot 6^{(N+3)/2}+\frac{(N+3)(N+2)}{2}\cdot 10\cdot 2\cdot 6^{(N+1)/2}+\frac{(N+3)(N+2)}{2}\cdot 10^{(N+1)/2}\cdot 2\cdot 6+10^{(N+3)/2}\cdot 2\quad\pmod N\\&\equiv 2\cdot 6^{(N+3)/2}+6\cdot 10\cdot 6^{(N+1)/2}+6\cdot 10^{(N+1)/2}\cdot 6+10^{(N+3)/2}\cdot 2\qquad\pmod N\\&\equiv 2(-6^2)+60(-6)+6\cdot (-10)\cdot 6+(-10^2)\cdot 2\qquad\pmod N\\&\equiv -992\qquad\pmod N\end{align}$$
from which we have
$$p^{(N+3)/2}+q^{(N+3)/2}\equiv -62\qquad\pmod N$$

Hence, from $(2)$,
$$\begin{align}p^{(N-1)/2}+q^{(N-1)/2}&=8(p^{(N+1)/2}+q^{(N+1)/2})-(p^{(N+3)/2}+q^{(N+3)/2})\\&\equiv 8(-8)-(-62)\qquad\pmod N\\&\equiv -2\qquad\pmod N\end{align}$$

Thus,
$$\begin{align}S_{n-2}^2&=(p^{(N-1)/4}+q^{(N-1)/4})^2\\&=p^{(N-1)/2}+q^{(N-1)/2}+2\\&\equiv 0\qquad\pmod N\end{align}$$
from which $S_{n-2}\equiv 0\pmod{N}$ follows.